# I am having trouble getting data from Google Place API AutoComplete

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-places-api

I need help, I am having trouble getting data from this link  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You get *data* from that link, you get an error message.

Please RTFM first.
The Google Place API needs an API key in order to work.

I'm quoting the error message from that url, which btw is asking you to RTFM first :-)

> You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

Comment: i did every steps but the link don't work